# jQuery, relative url on IE

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to generate jQuery vertical tabs using jQuery template. I use this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var clientData = [
                { name: "Rey Bango", age: 42, id: 1, phone: ["954-600-1234", "954-355-5555"] },
                { name: "Mark Goldberg", age: 51, id: 2, phone: ["954-600-1234", "954-355-5555"] },
                { name: "Jen Statford", age: "25", id: 3, phone: ["954-600-1234", "954-355-5555"] }
            ];

            $("#clientTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo($("#vtabs div ul"));
            $("#phoneTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo($("#vtabs div:last"));

            $("#vtabs").jVertTabs();
        });
    </script>

<script id="clientTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li><a href="#${id}">${name}</a></li>
</script>

<script id="phoneTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div id="${id}">
            <p>${name} - Age: ${age}</p>        
            <p>Some text on panel 1</p> 
    </div>
</script>
```

Everything works greate on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari but in IE this code doesn't work. When I looked at the html source I saw that in IE instead of

```
<li><a href="#1">${name}</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">${name}</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">${name}</a></li>
```

I get

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:51592/galeria-lista/#1">${name}</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:51592/galeria-lista/#2">${name}</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://localhost:51592/galeria-lista/#3">${name}</a></li>
```

Because of this the jQuery vertical tabs don't work in IE.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you using asp.net? if yes, is this in a user control?

Answer (score 0):

maybe some conflict with JQuery $
try use JQuery instead $